# Undo Actions Google Migration

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, actions-builder

I accidentally migrated my dialogflow to actions google. I made a mistake of migrating as a new project instead of 'this project' and I believe that is why my intents are not existing in Actions Google. I was wondering if anyone has ran into this issue and how they went about fixing this. Currently I am unable to delete my project and make a new one. I would like to see if anyone was able to reintegrate dialogflow into their actions google.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

The migration from Dialogflow to Actions Builder is one-way. Once it happens, it is not possible to reverse that.